Can't flip editor header to bottom anymore?
I can't right click on an editor header and flip it to the bottom of the editor anymore. Has this changed in 4.1?


"the menu"? What menu? Do you mean the header of every Editor? Or perhaps the main Blender header bar (actually do those two have different names)?

The menu with Object, pose, etc.  Updated with screen shot.

It looks as if you have to have Region Overlap unchecked under Preferences > Interface > Editors for that option menu to appear now. That was not the case in 4.0.1 and below.

@JohnEason This appears to be an answer. Please post it as such.

Thanks.  Wow. That is horrible.  I'm going to downgrade.  I don't like the new border and I don't like this menu on top.

Jimmy, he explained how to bring the option back in later versions. Hang on, I'll post it as an answer.

@TheLabCat Will do. it might be worth submitting that as a bug report because the Blender manual doesn't mention the change in 4.1 as far as I can see.

It seems that you need to uncheck RegionOverlap under Preferences > Interface > Editors to get that menu to appear in Blender 4.1.1.

If you leave the option checked, right-clicking just displays the normal Object menu.

That was not the case in versions before 4.1 so might be worth reporting as a bug via Help > Report a Bug.
ADDENDUM:
Apparently if you uncheck RegionOverlap, flip the menu position and then turn overlap back on the menu position will stay at the bottom, but you will have to save your startup file via File > Defaults > SaveStartupFile to retain the menu position.

Gah! Too late! :^)

Thank you John.  I found a way.  I followed your instructions and I had the borders I did not like but was able to flip to bottom.  But what is interesting here is, I turned Region Overlap back on and the menu stayed at the bottom.  This is too good to be true and I hope my future projects don't crash because of this.  I would never be able to debug the issue.

Good to know, but I still reckon it should be reported as a bug!

Do they care?  I feel like 10000's for people report bugs everyday and I'm just a drop in the bucket. And usually when I report something, it's already an existing issue.  It's very discouraging.

To enable the right-click menu for editor headers (including the "Flip to top/bottom" option) in >4.0.1, go into Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Editors, and uncheck "Region Overlap" as shown below:

Save the preferences so you won't have to do this every time you create a new file:

You should now have the editor header right-click menu, with the "Flip to top/bottom" option, as before:

Hope this helps!
